# ListIterator previous() and next() result

Tags: java, listiterator

result is

A B C D

D C C2 B2 B A

Why isn't result

A B B2 C D

D C C2 B2 B A    in first while ?

I did li.add("B2") if word.equals"B". Is it just difference between next() and previous() ? I want to know answer please.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D");
    list = new ArrayList<>(list);
    ListIterator<String> li = list.listIterator();
    String word;

    while (li.hasNext()) {
        word = li.next();
        System.out.print(word + '\t');
        if (word.equals("B"))
           li.add("B2");
    }

    System.out.println();

    while (li.hasPrevious()) {
        word = li.previous();
        System.out.print(word + '\t');
        if (word.equals("C"))
            li.add("C2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that answer for your question is here - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add(E).

> The element is inserted immediately before the element that would be returned by next(), if any, and after the element that would be returned by previous(), if any.
>
> The new element is inserted before the implicit cursor: a subsequent call to next would be unaffected, and a subsequent call to previous would return the new element.

At first loop when word equals "B" the implicit cursor is between "B" and "C", according to the documentation the new element will be added before it.

```
A    B       C     D
       ^   ^ 
      B2  cursor
```

Answer (score 1):

See [ListIterator.add(E)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add(E)):

> ... The element is inserted **immediately before** the element that would be returned by next() ...

So in your first iteration, the addition of `B2` will not become the next one in the list.

Comment: But in the second while, C2 become the next one in the list

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html

The reason is that when you are adding element to the iterator this is not changing the `next()` element but the `previous()` only. Thus when you add "B2" and "C2" it is only going to be picked up by `previous()` calls. And that's why the first iteration is not picking up B2 and C2 and the second backwards iteration picks both of them.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaDoc for `ListIterator#add` specifies the behaviour:

```
 * Inserts the specified element into the list (optional operation).
 * The element is inserted immediately before the element that
 * would be returned by {@link #next}, if any, and after the element
 * that would be returned by {@link #previous}, if any.  (If the
 * list contains no elements, the new element becomes the sole element
 * on the list.)  The new element is inserted before the implicit
 * cursor: a subsequent call to {@code next} would be unaffected, and a
 * subsequent call to {@code previous} would return the new element.
```

Where is the confusion?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the list change by changing your print to use `nextIndex` like this

```
System.out.print(list.get(li.nextIndex()) + "["+ li.nextIndex()+ "]" +'\t');


while (li.hasNext()) {
    System.out.print(list.get(li.nextIndex()) + "["+ li.nextIndex()+ "]" +'\t');
    word = li.next();
    if (word.equals("B")) {
         li.add("B2");
    }
  }

System.out.println();

while (li.hasPrevious()) {
    word = li.previous();
    System.out.print(list.get(li.nextIndex()) + "["+ li.nextIndex()+ "]" +'\t');
    if (word.equals("C"))
        li.add("C2");
    }
}
```

This outputs

```
A[0]    B[1]    C[3]    D[4]     
D[4]    C[3]    C2[3]   B2[2]   B[1]    A[0]
```

Comment: Thanks to answer. Using nextIndex helps me understand more.